# ASP.NET MVC hosting problem, routing, handlers and modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is one of them again, hosting with fasthosts.  I recently purchased a windows developer package from them.  When I tried to deploy my ASP.NET 3.5 MVC project, which was working fine with the same host on a reseller account, it is not working.  The reason to move from reseller to a normal Windows Developer package is, the MS-SQL server database is too expensive in a reseller account, strange!

I contact them, and they are saying they upgraded the control panel.  The technical support said, I need to disable the Modules and Handlers from the web.config file.  Also I need to deploy them as .dll files.  I am not sure how to do that.  The website is partially working now.  I think the problem is now with the routing.  I have not deployed any .dlls apart from the System.Web.Mvc.dll, System.Web.Routing.dll and System.Web.Abstractions.dll.  I have not got a clue on how to deploy the Modules and Handlers.  The code that I commented on the web.config file is as follows.

```
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</modules>

<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
       type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
       type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>-->
```

Anybody got any ideas please.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does Fasthosts actually have .NET 3.5 installed?  As far as I'm aware you shouldn't need to deploy any System* DLLs onto a .NET-enabled server

Comment: Hi Andy, Fasthosts got ASP.NET 3.5.  The website is okay in processing the Default.aspx page (which I included as per some suggestions).  I think it is the routing now.  When I click on the Home, it gives 
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home.aspx 

Any ideas?
Thank you for your time.